# " for vs find "

Tags: sed, find, for

I have alot of directories, the name of which are floating point numbers `(0, 0.5 ,...,199.5,200)`. All of these directories contain a text file named `p`. I want to replace the word `value` with `freeValue` in all of these text files. I tested two ways:

1. `find * -type f -readable -writable -name p -exec sed -i "s/value/freeValue/g" {} \;`

   After 10 minutes it returns nothing. It seems it doesn't work for some directories, independent of how many times I execute it.
2. `for file in */p; do sed -i "s/value/freeValue/g" "$file"; done`

   It worked perfectly.

The question is, what is wrong with the way I'm using `find`?

Comment: Why do you use `-readable` and `-writable`? It seems that your second option doesn't care if the file in readable or writable. Apart from that, I can't really see anything wrong with your `find `command (I would have used `.` instead of `*` though).

Comment: Are there subdirectories in the first level directories? `find` would enter these. If there are _many_ other files in the directories, this too could explain why it took longer (although you don't say how long the `for` loop takes). You could limit the depth for `find` with `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`, but really, if you know exactly where those `p` files are, there's no reason to use `find` at all.

Comment: Also, you mention it does not work for "some" directories. Are there anything special about these directories or the `p` files in them? (like permission-wise)

Comment: Technically, `find -writable` isn't the same as `sed -i` working, since the latter is likely to create a new file and rename it over the original, which requires write access to the _directory_, but not to the file itself, and `find -writable` looks at the permissions of the _file_. So you can have files where `-writable` is false, but which could be modified, and files where `-writable` is true, but which can't be modified. In general, I'd leave the condition out and just take the error messages if there are files that can't be handled, unless there's some particular reason to use it.

Comment: Sed can have multiple files as input: `sed -i 's/value/freeValue/g' */p`

Comment: You say your `find` command returns nothing. That should be true for both commands, as they will edit the files in place ... Please clarify.

Comment: if some of  files are actually links, `find -type f` will not find them whilst `for` will

Comment: @Kusalananda This is the directory in which I execute these commands: `ls` returns `0 0.5 ... 199.5 200`. Each folder contains files `p,U,V`. And finally there were nothing special with the directories where `sed` did not work.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thank you for your information.

Comment: @pLumo By "returns nothing", I mean terminal remains in a pending situation and the job remains incompleted for a relatively long time.

Comment: You have `find * ...` The first option to `find` is the dir to search, often times just `.`. Using `*` the shell will expand that to all files and directories in the current dir and start searching for the rest of the conditions in below your current $PWD. In an NFS environment, that can take a **long** time. Or did I miss something? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I will test this as soon as possible. Thnx.